# How to do sequential variable transforms on a TM variable in snippet?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, textmate

I'm working on a custom vscode snippet that, when typed on the same line  as a c++ function declaration, it will parse out the names of the various parameters to the function and format them in a comment. This is to aide in documentation in a standard used by my university. The problem is that I can't think of a good way to scrape off the things I don't want and replace some of the things in one transform.

For instance, I want to transform

```c
Class<T>::FunctionName(int* var1, string &var2, bool var3 = true){
```

into

```cpp
 * var1: 
 * var2:
 * var3:
```

as that will be on the inside of a larger multi-line comment. I can format the types and some of the punctuation into :\n* to make the list with some easy regex.

but this still leaves things to be removed (for instance, running this on the example function gives

```cpp
Class<T>::FunctionName:
* var1:
* var2:
* var3 = true{
```

Ideally I would do another transform to remove the rest of the things and add in the last :, but I can't find a way to do sequential transformations. So my question is this: is it possible to apply multiple variable transforms to a TM variable in a vscode snippet? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your snippet body so far?

Comment: there is no programmable logic in snippets currently, and you need a complex C++ parser to handle all cases.